# Powershell script not processing all lines but process few lines only

Tags: powershell

I am working on powershell script to convert an SNMP OID output which is in ASCII form to char. I am facing issue on converting more lines from a text file and it can process few lines only. If I add more lines then it process only few. I am unable to identify where the issue is on my script. Looking for guidance on where the issue might be.

Powershell script given below,

```
$FileName = "C:\LBOIDOUTSORT.txt"
if (Test-Path $FileName) {
  Remove-Item $FileName
}
Get-Content "C:\LBOIDOUT.txt"| Sort-Object | get-unique >> "C:\LBOIDOUTSORT.txt"
$RawData0 = Get-Content "C:\LBOIDOUTSORT.txt" -ReadCount 1000
$parentarray = @()
$parentarray += "URL Name,Server Name, IPAdress"
foreach ($RawDataline in $RawData0) {
    $rawinfo = $RawDataline  -replace ("ltmPoolMemberTable\.ltmPoolMemberEntry\.ltmPoolMemberAddr\.|%255255| OCTET STRING- \(ascii\): | ")
    $rawinfo = $rawinfo -split ':'
    $rawserverip = $rawinfo[1]
    $rawurlarray = $rawinfo[0] -split '\.'
    $temparray = @()
    foreach ($rawurlarrayvalue in $rawurlarray) {
        $oid = [int]$rawurlarrayvalue
        if (($oid -gt 44) -and ($oid -le 128)) {
            $oid = $oid
        }
        else {
            $oid = 32
        }
        $temparray += [char[]]$oid
    }
    $tempvalue = -join $temparray
    $childarray = $tempvalue -split '/'
    $servername = ($childarray[4] -replace " ")
    $urlserverip = ($childarray[2] -replace" ") + "," + $servername+","+$rawserverip
    $parentarray += $urlserverip
}
$parentarray
```

Sample Text file content used by the script.

ltmPoolMemberTable.ltmPoolMemberEntry.ltmPoolMemberAddr.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): 10.0.255.9%255255
ltmPoolMemberTable.ltmPoolMemberEntry.ltmPoolMemberAddr.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): 10.0.255.9%255255
ltmPoolMemberTable.ltmPoolMemberEntry.ltmPoolMemberAddr.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): 10.0.255.9%255255
ltmPoolMemberTable.ltmPoolMemberEntry.ltmPoolMemberAddr.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): 10.0.255.9%255255
ltmPoolMemberTable.ltmPoolMemberEntry.ltmPoolMemberAddr.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76.66.47.66.65.66.67.68.69.66.47.70.71.72.73.74.75.76 : OCTET STRING- (ascii): 10.0.255.9%255255

If I copy above content multiple times inside the text file the issue occurs.

Regards,
Naresh

Comment: A google of 1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.2.5.3.2.1.3 gives you all the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue after removing -readcount parameter from below line.

Old line

```
$RawData0 = Get-Content "C:\LBOIDOUTSORT.txt" -ReadCount 1000
```

Modified line

```
$RawData0 = Get-Content "C:\LBOIDOUTSORT.txt"
```

This resolved the issue.